# Set Hostname To Spring Boot Project In Ubuntu Server

Tags: spring-boot, ubuntu, nginx, dns

I'm running my spring boot project on ubuntu server 22.04. Its perfectly running on http://161.35.75.184:8055/. I want to set a hostname to it. I already have client1.mdholding.uz dns working. I installed nginx and made configurations.

```
root@crm-azizkhuja:/etc/nginx/sites-available# nano client1.mdholding.uz

  GNU nano 6.4                                                        client1.mdholding.uz                                                                  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name client1.mdholding.uz;
    index index.html index.htm;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/client1.mdholding.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/client1.mdholding-error.log error;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://161.35.75.184:8055;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

}
```

Then i entered this command:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/client1.mdholding.uz /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/client1.mdholding.uz
```

And restarted nginx:

```
 sudo nginx -t
 sudo nginx -s reload
```

When i run my spring boot project using `./mvnw spring-boot:run` and try to access it using hostname:

http://client1.mdholding.uz/welcome

it says: Cant access to website, meanwhile it works if i access it on http://161.35.75.184:8055/welcome

I disabled the firewall and nothing blocks from accessing to my ubuntu server ip.

```
; <<>> DiG 9.18.12-0ubuntu0.22.10.2-Ubuntu <<>> client1.mdholding.uz
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 34191
;; flags: qr aa rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;client1.mdholding.uz.          IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
client1.mdholding.uz.   0       IN      A       161.35.75.184

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Mon Jul 24 12:25:14 UTC 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 65
```

Also, i tried to send curl request: `curl http://client1.mdholding.uz/welcome but got: curl: (7) Failed to connect to client1.mdholding.uz port 80 after 0 ms: Connection refused`

```
root@crm-azizkhuja:/etc/nginx/sites-available# nslookup client1.mdholding.uz
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

Name:   client1.mdholding.uz
Address: 161.35.75.184
```

What should i do next?

Comment: Can you please give us the exact config file inside `sites-enabled` and also the `nginx.conf` from `/etc/nginx`? Also you should be able to use the localhost port inside the proxy pass, might be a better option overall. Having the configuration files we can have a more precise look into it.